# Did anyone before Augustine teach Original Sin?

Tags: early-church, adam-and-eve, original-sin

From what I understand Augustine was the first to introduce the idea of original sin. Did anyone before Augustine state that Adam and Eve's sin was a punishment to all humanity?

Comment: "Adam and Eve's sin was a punishment to all humanity" Do you mean that all humanity was punished for Adam and Eve's sin?

Comment: @curiousdannii whats the difference between the two? Punishment to all humanity or all humanity punished?

Comment: Good question!  But it looks very similar to an older one that might provide some insight, so I've closed this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Nathaniel thanx. I missed that. Sorry. Sometimes my app doesnt pull up corresponding questions or even tgs